# does stopService kills child threads from service

Tags: android, android-service

I've an android service that runs in background...
it create threads to run is sub-taks

In certain circunstances i do need to restart the service... i'm doing this like:

```
 stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
 startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

my question is, if during the `stopService` call the service had some sub-tasks running in child threads those threads are killed or keep running?

my app is min api lvl 16 (i dont know if it makes any difference)

Answer (score 1):

> does stopService kills child threads from service

No.

> those threads are killed or keep running?

They keep running, until your process is terminated. That might be milliseconds or minutes after your `stopService()` call.